# TypeScript Syntax Question about string building

Tags: javascript, typescript

What does the following syntax do in TypeScript?

```
export interface Config {
readonly name: string
readonly buildPath: (data?: Data) => string
readonly group: string
}

export interface Data {
  id: number
  account: string
  group: 'a' | 'b' | 'b'
}

so what does the following method do?

config.buildPath(data)
given data = Data(15, 'largeAccount', 'c')
```

Comment: `Config` is an interface, so `buildPath` defines the signature of a function accepting a data object and returning a string. What the method does is defined by the **implementation** of it, which is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here the interface Data is used to define the format of the object that is supposed to be accepted by the buildPath function. This is known as type specific data.

You can also pass the direct object

```
{id:5,account:'largeAccount',group:'c'}
```

Even this would be accepted but to avoid any mistake this approach is the best to follow.

**buildPath** is just the function that takes **Data** as argument and returns the string.

**config** is the interface that declares the **buildPath** function alongwith other two variables.

Now what **buildPath** does is to be decided by the implementation that writes the logic behind it.